# Counts how many times given number appears in a given array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need write a method that counts how many times given number appears in a given array.
On the first line I'll receive a number **N** - the size of the array.
On the second line I'll receive **N** numbers separated by spaces - the numbers in the array. On the third line I'll receive a number **X**

My program needs to print how many times the number X appears in the array. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AppearanceCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[n];
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] == x) {
            count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: `On the third line I'll receive a number X` - it looks like you are reading X **before** reading the N input numbers, which is not what you say you should do.

Comment: ^ That - To fix it move the `int x = scanner.nextInt();` down to **below** the first loop.

Comment: I'm blind... Thanks!